# Insert a div class inside wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">About Assetline</a>
    <li><a href="#">Products & Services</a>
        <div id="mega">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Commercial Credit</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio Management</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--mega-->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News & Events</a>
</ul>
```

This is the menu structure what I want to integrate into WordPress . But there's an issue to add a div id ( ) inside of a menu . Any idea to achieve this ?

Comment: why you want to add div ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close some of your first li tags. If that does work, remove the div, and assign the id in the child ul.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>level 1</a>
     <ul id="mega">
       <li>
          <a>level 2 A</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a>level 2 B</a>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <a>level 3</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```